# Creating QTreeView hierarchy from a given list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

Given a list of strings, I am trying to populate the items in a tree view.
Here is my code:

```
class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.get_contents()

    def get_contents(self):
        self.clear()
        contents = [
            '|Base|character|Mike|body',
            '|Base|character|John',
            '|Base|camera'
        ]

        for content in contents:
            count = content.count('|')
            for index in range(count):
                index = index + 2
                split_path = content.split('|')[0:index]
                self.add_item(split_path)

    def add_item(self,name):
        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
        self.appendRow([item1])
```

However, the hierarchy that I have got in my Tree View are not collapsible (those with the small arrow icons by the side) and each row is appended with values and editable (if double click), in which I do not want.

An example of the output from my code:

```
|Base
|Base|character
|Base|character|Mike
|Base|character|Mike|body
|Base
|Base|character
|Base|character|John
|Base
|Base|camera
```

where there are a few repeatable rows...

And this is what I am expecting:

```
|-- Base
|--|-- character
|--|--|-- Mike
|--|--|--|-- body
|--|-- character
|--|--|-- John
|--|-- camera
```

Any insights?

Comment: @eyllanesc It will be pyqt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the children if this is not part of the children, also you must remove the first element of the result of the `split()` since it is an empty element:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.get_contents()

    def get_contents(self):
        self.clear()
        contents = [
            '|Base|character|Mike|body',
            '|Base|character|John',
            '|Base|camera'
        ]

        for content in contents:
            parent = self.invisibleRootItem()
            for word in content.split("|")[1:]:
                for i in range(parent.rowCount()):
                    item = parent.child(i) 
                    if item.text() == word:
                        it = item
                        break
                else:
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem(word)
                    parent.setChild(parent.rowCount(), it)
                parent = it


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QTreeView()
    model = MyModel(w)
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()
    w.expandAll()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is it possible to change the sizing eg. making the items to appear bigger? And/ Or re-iterates each item in the `QStandardItemModel` again such that I will be re-getting back '|Base', '|Base|character' etc..?

Comment: @dissidia What do you mean by changing the size? Do you want to change the size of the items by changing the size of the font?

Comment: Yes, changing the font to make it bigger

Comment: Hey, sorry for jumping onto your thread. I am doing something similiar, in which I am trying to add in a refresh functionality. 
I tried using `<model>.clear()` and followed by re-calling the `MyModel()` which does not seems to work - The contents did get emptied and it stays blank all the way...

Comment: @yan Are you using QStandardItemModel?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yup, doing almost the same thing as what dissidia wanted.

Comment: @yan without an MCVE I could not help you, so I invite you to post a question

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, while this may sounds stupid of me, but say if I am planning to append different icons besides each row of item, will it be better for me to iterate each item before/ after setting the model?

Comment: @dissidia at any time, if you can do it before or after, have you tried something ?, I recommend asking when you have a real problem, that is, when you have tried something to avoid speculation.